# Python: How to ask the user for the index of a list

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, user-input

-------Answered, turns out I was doing the right thing, but had a different error that made me think it was the wrong thing to do------------------

Alright, so I know this is super simple but I am really confused as to how to take a user input as a number and use that number to index from a list with that number.
So what I am trying to do is this:
Enter your choice: (User enters a 1)
You choose 1.
Which sentence? (User enters a 0 or whatever number they want within the bounds of how many sentences they enter)

I then just want to use their inputted number and index that from the list.
So if they entered these two sentences for their list:
good
bad

Then when they ask which sentence, and say 1, I want to index sentenceList[1] and print it back to them.

But this needs to be scale-able to any number, so sentenceList[variable],
but I do not know how to properly do this.

Thanks, I know this might be confusing.

```
#declare variable
TOTAL_SENTENCES = 5


def main():

 #print greeting
 print ('This program will demonstrate lists')

 #establish array sentences
 sentenceList = list()

 #prompt user for how many sentences to store (assume integer, but if 
 negative, set to 5)
 TOTAL_SENTENCES = int(input('How many sentences? '))
 if TOTAL_SENTENCES < 0:
    TOTAL_SENTENCES = 5
 else:
    pass

 #store in a list in all lower case letters (assume no period at the end)
 while len(sentenceList) < TOTAL_SENTENCES:
    userSentence = input('Enter a sentence: ')
    sentenceList.append(userSentence.lower())

 #print 5 options for the user to choose from (looping this for the total 
 number of sentences)
 for i in range(TOTAL_SENTENCES):
    print ('Enter 1 to see a sentence\n' 'Enter 2 to see the whole list\n'
           'Enter 3 to change a sentence\n' 'Enter 4 to switch words\n'
           'Enter 5 to count letters')

    #prompt user for their choice
    userChoice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    #print their choice back to them
    print ('You selected choice' ,userChoice)

    #prompt for which sentence                         
    #CHOICE-1 (pull from the list and print the sentence)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you're having trouble here. You've already converted the input to an int, so why can't you just use it as an index?

Comment: Okay, sorry if it was confusing. How do I use the user input of a number, as the number in the index?

Comment: userInput = 1, sentenceList[userInput]

Comment: Er, exactly like that. Did you try?

Comment: Yup, edited the top of the post, I was doing it right but had an error that made me think I was doing that wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, in the last line of your code, if you want to pull up a sentence from the list `sentenceList`, you can just write:

```
print(sentenceList[userChoice-1])
```

Note that I wrote `userChoice-1`. This is because people usually are going to number the sentences from 1 to N. But Python's internal list numbering is from 0 to N-1.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: the use of `print` in parentheses suggests OP is using Python 3.x, in which case `input` is the correct approach.